# SQL: Syntax Error after Having (Select ...) table

Tags: sql, create-table, having, having-clause

The question is to extract information about customer that spent the most (in total over their lifetime as a customer) total_amt_usd, and COUNT the web_events they had for each channel.

I am trying to create an extra table from original table, and both of tables are needed to extract information. However, I keep getting syntax error and unable to proceed further.

```
SELECT t1.acc, COUNT(w.channel) total,
sum(case when w.channel = 'direct' then 1 else 0 end) direct,
sum(case when w.channel = 'adwords' then 1 else 0 end) adwords,
sum(case when w.channel = 'banner' then 1 else 0 end) banner,
sum(case when w.channel = 'facebook' then 1 else 0 end) facebook,
sum(case when w.channel = 'organinc' then 1 else 0 end) organic,
sum(case when w.channel = 'twitter' then 1 else 0 end) twitter
FROM web_events w
HAVING (
    SELECT o.account_id acc, SUM(o.total_amt_usd) total
    FROM orders o
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t1
GROUP BY t1.acc
```

The syntax error is near at 't1' at the end of table after Having and before group by.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Your `having` clause doesn't make sense to me either.  (3) What is `t1`?

Comment: Only subqueries in the FROM list can be given aliases.

Comment: Can you describe in words what your intentions are with the query?

Comment: @jarlh: and of course - those in the `JOIN` clauses, too - if there are any

Comment: @marc_s, the JOIN clauses are parts of the FROM clause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include only accounts with orders -- my best guess as to what you might be attempting -- I would suggest a `where` clause with `exists`:

```
SELECT w.account_id, COUNT(w.channel) total,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'direct' then 1 else 0 end) as direct,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'adwords' then 1 else 0 end) as adwords,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'banner' then 1 else 0 end) as banner,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'facebook' then 1 else 0 end) as facebook,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'organinc' then 1 else 0 end) as organic,
       sum(case when w.channel = 'twitter' then 1 else 0 end) as twitter
FROM web_events w
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM orders o
              WHERE o.account_id = w.account_id
             )
GROUP BY w.account_id;
```